# how to create a nested dynamic reactive from Controls in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Can you please help me with better code logic to create the nested form controls for the model object shown below.

```
    questions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "parent question1",
      selected: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: 11,
          title: "child question11",
          selected: false,
          children: [
            {
              id: 111,
              title: "child child question111",
              selected: false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "parent question2",
      selected: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: 21,
          title: "child question21",
          selected: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "parent question2",
      selected: false
    }
  ];
```

and want to create the view with checkboxes, and would need to create the child questions beneath to parent question.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)">
<hr>
    <div formArrayName="questions">
        <div *ngFor="let question of form.get('questions').controls; let i = index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected">
        {{question.value.title}}
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

```
{{form.value | json }}
```

Comment: Read this Article https://medium.com/@m.kunwa52/reactive-form-in-angular-with-formarray-2595e5ee1d31